# Understanding about constructor in Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

My web api looks like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ValuesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        // get random user

        var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault();

        return user?.Email ?? "";
    }
}
```

Trying to call it via jquery:

```
$.get('/api/values', function (email) {
    console.log(email)
})
```

I've 2 questions:

**1/.** Why didn't `console.log(email)` work although I was getting the response successful?

[image: 1]

There was nothing in the `Console` tab.

**2/.** When I made a request to server (`/api/values`), the breakpoint had been caught:

[image: 2]

My question: where had `ValuesController` been called within `context`? I'd sent a request from client, then the constructor was hit (I'm sure that I didn't send something like `ApplicationDbContext` from client to server :v)

**UPDATE:** By changing `$.get('/api/values', {}, function (email) {}` to `$.get('/api/values', function (email) {}`. I've fixed the first problem. It's my bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you still have an issue after you change from `$.get('/api/values', {}, function (email)`  to `$.get('/api/values', function (email) `?

Comment: @Win I'm sorry. I just update the question with an explaining. My bad.

Comment: The second one has nothing to do with the request pipeline or what you send. Your request parameters will be passed via controller actions. Constructor has nothing do to with the request.You need to learn more about some concepts like dependency injection, before continue to developing your application, its vital to understand it.

Comment: @Tseng I would, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Shorter Answer

> My question: where had ValuesController been called within context? I'd sent a request from client, then the constructor was hit.

The HTTP Request arrived. ASP.NET MVC Routing told the application to use the `ValuesController` to handle the request. The application constructed the `ValuesController`, supplying an instance of `ApplicationDbContext` via dependency injection.

## Longer Answer

The `Startup.Configure` method is used to specify how the ASP.NET application will respond to individual HTTP requests. Since you are using Web API, you have configured `app.UseMvc()`. Result: when an HTTP Request arrives, MVC Routing tells the application to use the appropriate controller.

The `Startup.ConfigureServices` method is used to specify services that are available via dependency injection. Since you are injecting an `ApplicationDbContext` into your constructor, you have configured `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()`. Result: when the application constructs a `ValuesController`, ASP.NET Dependency Injection will provide an instance of the `ApplicationDbContext`.